# AGPL - Api usage

Tags: licensing, agpl-3.0, api

I am currently working on a workout app for a gym and in my research stumbled upon wger.

https://wger.de/en/software/license.

An API distributed under AGPL.

My question is the following:
Does the usage of the API (sending requests to it and doing something with the data) also fall under AGPL, meaning I am required to make the code of the app publicly available or does that only fall under the API itself (meaning if I modify the API I would make those modifications available)?

Comment: The usage of which api by whom?

Comment: You say it's "*An API distributed under AGPL.*", but it's not: [wger](https://github.com/wger-project/wger) is a complete piece of server software.  Are you asking whether, if you were to re-implement this server yourself, the re-implementation would also have to be under AGPLv3?  Or are you asking whether, if you were to implement your own client for interacting with an existing wger installation, the client would have to be AGPLv3?  Or something else?

Comment: I'm asking if I'm connecting to this API via a client (making get requests) does my client has to be distributed under AGPL as well?